# Como utilizo um mesmo argumento/parâmetro em duas funções diferentes?

Tags: python

Exemplo:

```
 def seno1(x = int(input("Entre com x: ")),n=int(input("Entre com n: "))):
 def cos1(x,n):
```

Como faço para aproveitar o valor inputado pelo usuário do x e do n nessa função também?

Obrigado

Answer (score 4):

Não tente fazer tud em uma única linha - simplesmente atribua variáveis para os seus parâmetros digitados com `input`:

```
def seno1(x, n):
   ...
def cos1(x,n):
   ...

# e mais abaixo no seu código ponha o trecho:
x = int(input("Entre com x: "))
n = int(input("Entre com n: "))

print(seno1(x, n))
print(cos1(x, n))
```

Dessa forma você vai estar *de fato* usando suas funções como funções e não só para reorganizar o código, mas ainda sem serem reutilizaveis (por que do jeito que você fez, aqueles input só seriam executados uma vez, mesmo que voce chamasse a função seno1 várias vezes) -
e se colocar o input e as chamadas dentro de um while ou de outra função, pode ter um programa completo que refaz os cálculos com vários valores.

Answer (score 1):

*Acredito que o melhor seja seguir a sugestão do @jsbueno (isto é um complemento).*

> Aproveitando o seu código, você pode usar varáveis globais (não indicado):

```
def seno1(x = int(input("Entre com x: ")),n=int(input("Entre com n: "))):
    global xg # cria variável global para x
    global ng
    xg = x # copia x para a variável
    ng = n
```

> Para utilizá-las, entretanto, você teria que chamar a função `seno1()`:

```
seno1() # chama função
print('variavel global x: ' + str(xg)) // mostra valor de x, fora de seno1()
print('variavel global n: ' + str(ng))
```

---

> Uma terceira opção é colocar o input do usuário em outra função:

```
def inputUsuario():
    x = int(input("Entre com x:"))
    n = int(input("Entre com n:"))
    return(x, n)
```

> E usá-lo depois numa versão modificada de seno1():

```
def seno1(x, y): # versão modificada de seno1(), só imprime variáveis
    print('x: ' + str(x) + ', y: ' + str(y))

# utilizando as duas funções

minhaVar = inputUsuario()
seno1(minhaVar[0], minhaVar[1])
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]